# bring the output of compositing into blender material node editor

Tags: compositing-nodes

Hi is it possible to pipe the output of compositor directly into the material node editor ? the current workflow i use seems cumbersome, where i need to render out (file out) first then reimport inside material editor. It will be a lot practical and faster to bring the compositor output to material editor directly without rendering first.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't possible, perhaps you can describe your overall goal. Maybe there are other methods.

Comment: The overall goal is to be able to edit material/ texture without have to go to app such as pohotoshop etc. we can setup texture , modify , add filter etc then use it as material. simple thing is to mask/rotoscope or add alpha channel to the texture. For this simple task i have to go to photoshop or maybe edit it first in blender compositor then render it out as new image and  imported back to BLender to use as material/texture.

Answer (score 1):

Compositing is a process that happens after rendering. Materials are input for rendering. Basically it is not possible to change these steps expect when rendering out to an image and then import it in a material node.

This fixed pipeline is normal in animations and vfx. Compositing in these kings of pipelines are used to tweak the renderings without doing full re-renders.

Comment: Thanks, if we think the compositing as the post process after rendering then this is fine. But i'm trying to make this compositing workflow not as a post processing tool, but as pre processing tools such as you can edit and prepare all texture material (add blur, transform, masking merging multiple texture etc) and the feed it into the object material before we render the scene.

Answer (score 0):

You possibly could create an image texture in the node editor and have it linked to the composited image? I don't know why you'd need to do that, but it maybe might work